# Different behavior between ref and pointer

Tags: c++, casting

This is just an oddity I ran into and can't quite understand what's happening.

```
int main()
{
    int i{ 5 };

    void* v = &i;

    int* t = reinterpret_cast<int*>(v);
    int u = reinterpret_cast<int&>(v);

    int i2 = *t;

}
```

t is correctly 5 and u is garbage.

What's going on?

Comment: Simply put, reinterpreting a pointer as a reference doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v` stores the address of `i`, which is, as you put it, garbage. (it's not really garbage, but the value itself is meaningless, except as it is the address of `i` in this particular run of the program). `u` stores the same value (bitwise) as `v`, but reinterpreted as an integer, so it is "garbage".

`t` is not 5, as you claim. Or if it is, it's an extremely unlikely coincidence. `t` is the address of `i`, and `i` is 5, so `*t` (that is, `t` dereferenced) is 5.

Comment: What I meant was the debugger resolved the address, so I did indead see 5 as the pointed to value.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%x %x\n", u, v);
```

for me prints:

```
39fdb8 39fdb8
```

Not garbage, but the value of `v`.

Comment: Yeah. total brain fart. That's what happens after a long day of manipulating void*s. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

u is int v is pointer  *v is int, but we should 
the following code can output 5 5

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i{ 5 };

    void* v = &i;

    int* t = reinterpret_cast<int*>(v);
    int u = reinterpret_cast<int&>(*(int*)v);

    int i2 = *t;

    std::cout << *t << std::endl;
    std::cout << u << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to mix c++ and c styles of casting. In this case it's simple enough: `int u = reinterpret_cast<int&>(*v);`

Comment: @vershov No so simple I'm afraid, `void` is an incomplete type

Comment: @Praetorian reinterpret_cast is a compiler directive which instructs the compiler to treat the sequence of bits of expression as if it had the type <new_type>.

Comment: @vershov Fascinating, but how do you dereference a `void *`?

Comment: @Praetorian `void* v` is a pointer that is just an address to the memory. `*v` is sequence of bits located at the place where the pointer points to. Once we pass sequence of bits to the `reinterpret_cast` we don't need anything else to build new type, just this bit's sequence.

Comment: @vershov I apologize, it seems you're right. It is indeed just the starting location that matters in this context. Can't say I've ever tried to `reinterpret_cast` a `void*` to an `int&` before, so thank you for teaching me something new. Edit: Or maybe not, both VS2013 and gcc4.8 [agree with my earlier assertion](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ddd4dba142009e0), but clang compiles and outputs the correct answer.

Comment: @vershov I posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178903/reinterpret-cast-behavior-when-dereferencing-a-void-pointer), let's see if someone can shed light on the difference in behavior